When is Tukey post hoc test result identical to Games Howell post hoc test for Welch ANOVA?
In what situations is the Tukey post hoc test identical to the Games Howell post hoc test? I have an ANOVA analysis where HOV is violated and I have a statistically significant Welch ANOVA result. I read online somewhere that there are situations where running a Tukey post hoc test produces identical results to Games Howell. However, I cannot find this source online again and I do not remember it being specific enough to provide me a clear answer anyway. I would like to find out if I can use Tukey results validly because it is my understanding that to run Games Howell in SAS, it requires using a macro from online, and I would like to keep my coding and process simpler if I can do so with validity. Here is an example of my ANOVA syntax:
proc glm data=data1;
class PtGroup;
model AvgFURxLen = PtGroup/ solution;
means PtGroup / hovtest=levene(type=abs);
means PtGroup / hovtest=bartlett;
means PtGroup / welch tukey;
run;

Is there any way to know whether Tukey would be valid for my analysis, or more broadly, when is Tukey identical to Games Howell? Thank you
